# Oracle MAF: Too many Android emulators connected. Only one emulator should be connected for deployment

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I am trying to deploy my first MAF application on android emulator. When am trying to deploy application it is giving the following error.

```
[10:33:07 AM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[10:33:07 AM] Target platform is  (Android).
[10:33:07 AM] Beginning deployment of MAF application "MyFirstApp" to Android using profile "myMafAndrd".
[10:33:09 AM] Checking state of Android Debug Bridge server...
[10:33:10 AM] Android Debug Bridge server already running.
[10:33:14 AM] Verifying a single Android emulator is online and connected to the ADB server...
[10:33:15 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[10:33:15 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[10:33:15 AM] Too many Android emulators connected.  Only one emulator should be connected for deployment.  The following results were provided by ADB:
List of devices attached
emulator-5556   device
emulator-5554   device
 (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.CheckAttachedDevicesDeployer)
```

But I have only one emulator in AVD Manager. 
[image]

I searched a lot on google and find that I have to restart adb server using adb kill-server and restart it using start-server. It also did not solve my problem.

I started my emulator. And on console I have typed the following.

```
L:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb devices -l
List of devices attached
emulator-5554          device product:t03gxx model:GT_N7100 device:t03g
emulator-5556          device product:sdk_phone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_
x86 device:generic_x86
```

Even though I have only one emulator in AVD Manager why it is showing list of devices connected as two. Because of this I am unable to deploy my app.

How do I can disconnect `emulator-5554          device product:t03gxx model:GT_N7100 device:t03g` my actual emulator is `emulator-5556          device product:sdk_phone_x86` . Please help. Thanks in ADvance.

Comment: Try abd kill-server to kill adb, then relaunch it by running adb devices.  See if that clears the bad connection.

Comment: Hello Thanks for you time. I tried your solution .... 
L:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>kill adb
kill: illegal pid: adb

Comment: Not kill adb.  adb kill-server

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I already tried this. Now also I tried . Its not working. Same problem in Jdeveloper. Too Many devices connected.

Comment: Try launching a process manager and killing all the emulators you can find.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new deployment profile in JDeveloper?

Comment: Yes I have created a new deployment profile in jDeveloper